# Python setup.py install specify extras_require

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I have "extras_require" declared in setup.py. Is there a way I can specify optional features with something like `python setup.py[extras] install`?

I know that `pip` can handle optional features like:

```bash
pip install .[extras]
```

or

```bash
pip install -e .[extras]
```

Is there something like `python setup.py install [extras]` or `python setup.py develop [extras]` that can do something similar? Or is there another way to tell `python setup.py` to install some optional requirements?

Comment: What's wrong with `pip install .[extras]`?

Comment: Or even `pip install --no-binary .[extras] ` to enforce `setup.py install`?

Answer (score 10):

```
python setup.py install easy_install "pkg_name[extras]"
```

or

```
python setup.py develop easy_install "pkg_name[extras]"
```

This requires `pkg_name` to already exist in the search paths. Note that `easy_install` shouldn't install `pkg_name` a second time (since the `install`/`develop` option would've already installed it), but it will process & install the `extras`.

The advantage of this over `pip install (options) ".[extras]"` is that you can pass specific options to `build`/`install`/`develop`.

Comment: Note that many UNIX shells need you to quote `[` and `]` characters, so it is safer to give `python setup.py install easy_install "pkg_name[extras]"` as general instructions